# Implementing a search bar to filter list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of items that I want people to be able to filter through using a search bar. The list is currently separated into 6 categorys, when you click a category title it's content is displayed.

It's the content of these categories i'd like users to be able to search through.

I have added the search bar, that should automatically filter as you type but it isn't working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var tcc = new $.ToClickControl($('.infoContainer'));

$('#box').keyup(function(){
 var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(valThis == ""){
   $('.three-quarters-column > li').show();
  } else {
   $('.three-quarters-column > li').each(function(){
   var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
  });
 };
});

});

;(function($) {

    $.ToClickControl = function(el, options) {

        var defaults = {
            activeClass: 'activeOption',

            onCallback: function() {}
        };

        var plugin = this;

        plugin.settings = {};

        var init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            plugin.el = el;

            active();
            bindEvents();
        };

        plugin.Destroy = function() {
            unbindEvents();
            plugin.el.removeData();
        };

        var bindEvents = function() {
            var select_container = plugin.el.find('.selectOptions');
            var matching_container = plugin.el.find('.matchingOptions');
            var activeClass = plugin.settings.activeClass;

            select_container.find('p').on('click', function() {
                if( $(this).attr('title') && !$(this).hasClass(activeClass) ) {

                    plugin.el.find('.' + activeClass).removeClass(activeClass);
                    $(this).addClass(activeClass);

                    matching_container.find('div[title]').hide('fast');
                    findMatch(matching_container, $(this).attr('title') ).show('fast');

                }
            });
        };

        var unbindEvents = function() {

        };

        var findMatch = function( container, title ) {
            return container.children('div[title="' + title + '"]');
        };

        var active = function() {
            var select_container = plugin.el.find('.selectOptions');
            var matching_container = plugin.el.find('.matchingOptions');
            var activeClass = plugin.settings.activeClass;

            if( plugin.el.find('.' + activeClass) )
                findMatch(matching_container, select_container.find('.' + activeClass).attr('title') ).show();
        };

        init();

    };

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.subMainContent {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:80px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 line-height:30px;
}
.subMainContent h1 {
 font-family: 'Oswald';
}
.subMainContent img {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.subMainContent .leftColumn {
 width: 50%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 float:left;
 padding-right: 40px;
}
.subMainContent .rightColumn {
 width: 49%;
 padding-left: 40px;
 float:left;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.subMainContent .rightColumn ul {
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

@media all and (max-width:768px) {
 .subMainContent {
  padding:20px;
 }
 .subMainContent .leftColumn {
  width:100%;
  padding-right: 0px;
 }
 .subMainContent .rightColumn {
  width:100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Search" id="box" type="text" />
<div class="infoContainer">
<div class="quarter-column selectOptions">


<p class="activeOption" title="1">Centre for American Studies</p>

<p title="2">School of Architecture</p>

<p title="3">School of Arts</p>

<p title="4">School of English</p>

<p title="5">School of European Culture and Language</p>

<p title="6">School of History</p>
</div>

<div class="three-quarters-column matchingOptions">
<div title="1">
<li>
<h4>UG American Studies School Rep</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG American Studies Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG American Studies Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

</div>

<div title="2">
<li>
<h4>UG Architecture Stage 2</h4>

<p>No Valid Votes</p>
</li>
</div>

<div title="3">
<li>
<h4>UG Drama Joint Honours Stage 2</h4>

<p>Tabitha Andrews-Speed</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Drama Joint Honours Stage 3</h4>

<p>Ellesse Cooke</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Drama Stage 2</h4>

<p>Sophie Burkhardt</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Drama Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Drama Stage 4</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Film Joint Honours Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Film Joint Honours Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG Film Stage 2</h4>

<p>Elena Morresi</p>
</li>

<li>
<h4>UG History and Philosophy of Art Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</li>
</div>

<div title="4">
<h4>UG English School Rep</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG Creative Writing Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG Creative Writing Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG English Literature Stage 2</h4>

<p>No Valid Votes</p>

<h4>UG English Literature Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</div>

<div title="5">
<h4>UG Classics and Archaeology Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG Comparative Literature Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG Comparative Literature Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG English Language and Linguistics Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG English Language and Linguistics Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG French Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG German Stage 2</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG German Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG Hispanic Studies Stage 2</h4>

<p>No Valid Votes</p>

<h4>UG Hispanic Studies Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG Italian Stage 2</h4>

<p>Alice Cripps</p>

<h4>UG Italian Stage 3</h4>

<p>No Valid Votes</p>

<h4>UG Religious Studies Stage 3</h4>

<p>No Valid Votes</p>
</div>

<div title="6">
<h4>UG History Joint Honours Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>

<h4>UG History Stage 2</h4>

<p>No Valid Votes</p>

<h4>UG War Studies Stage 3</h4>

<p>Vacant</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/ovd5u25n/1/

Update JS

```
$('#box').on('keyup',function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();    
      if(valThis == ""){
        $('.three-quarters-column li').show();
      } else {
        $('.three-quarters-column li').each(function(i,item){
        var text = $(item).text().toLowerCase();
        console.log($(item).find('p').text());
        if(text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
         $(item).show()         
        }
        else{
            $(item).hide();
        }
      });
    };
  });
```

Comment: Search is working in your site. Can you please explain whats your need?

Comment: its Ok. You are welcome. And your website is looking nice . :)